# How to trigger Airflow DAG from AWS SQS?

Tags: airflow, amazon-sqs

I would like to trigger an Airflow DAD based on SQS messages. I am quite new to Airflow but this is how I think it should be done:

### Option 1

Use the [Airflow SQS Sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/aws_sqs_sensor/index.html). From my understanding, this waits on SQS messages to proceed with the execution of an *already trigger* DAG. Does this mean a DAG would always need to be running and waiting for SQS messages to catch any eventual new messages and process them? Does this also mean I should schedule my DAG on a very short interval so that when an SQS message gets handled by a DAG, another DAG is created to handle the next SQS messages?

### Option 2

Add a lambda or something watching for SQS messages and using the [Airflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) to trigger DAGs when needed.

Eventually, I would like to minimise the number of interactions needed to trigger a DAG so I would like to use an Airflow built-in way of watching SQS.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Both options are valid however Option 2 is basically an alternative implementation to sensor. I think the better solution is Option 1 with some modification:

Use `SqsSensor` but with `mode='reschedule'` that way every once in a while the sensor is "awaking" checking if the criteria is met. Note that this is not like `sleep(x)`. When the criteria isn't met Airflow will release the worker for other tasks that needs to run and return the `SqsSensor` to the scheduling queue.
You can read more about the sensor modes in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base/index.html).

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.sqs import SqsSensor
SqsSensor(
    task_id='test_task',
    dag=dag,
    sqs_queue='your_queue',
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    mode='reschedule')
```

Note that the sensor will run indefinitely until the criteria is met. You can set `timeout` on the sensor task (there are other possible reasons for timeout like cluster policy and other defaults but that is another topic).

Comment: How would the sensor option handle a high peak load of incoming SQS messages? Will it be limited to the frequency it is scheduled at? Meaning if it is scheduled to run every second and that 2 incoming messages arrive every second, it would never be able to drain it completely?

Comment: You are confusing between DAG `schedule_interval` and sensor poking. Once the DAG is running the `schedule_interval` is irrelevant. You can set the sensor with `poke_interval` according to your needs.